# Turn a column table to a row

Tags: mysql, pivot-table, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table `gm_foldernames` and it has only one column.names type varchar(255). That column is a foreign key to another table in the bd, table1. I want to turn that column of names into a row maintaining the foreign key structure. 
i am using group_concat() to put the cells in column table into a row seperated by comma. however, when i do that i lose my foreign key. I wanna keep the foreign key structure
here is my code;

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(names) As names FROM gm_foldernames;
```

this is my current table. names is foreign key referencing another table

*names
ABRUZZO
ANZA
AQABA
...
...
...
I would like maintain the foreign key structure and make the column--> rows
ABRUZZO | ANZA | AQABA | ...
with the new column names being foreign key to the other table in the db

Comment: Is your database MySQL or SQL Server?  They are two different databases.

Comment: mysql sorry i should specify

Comment: Your question is hard to understand.  Can you update it with what the data looks like in the table(s), and what your desired output would be?

Comment: updated...hope it makes more sense

Comment: A SELECT does not change anything in the table.  In particular, the FOREIGN KEY is unaffected.